# Finding the action to Dummit and Foote 4.3.17

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, group-actions

Let $A$ be a nonempty set, $X$ any subset of $S_A$, $F(X)=\{a\in A:\sigma(a)=a\;\forall \sigma\in X\}$, and $M(X)=A-F(X)$ be the elements that are moved by some element of $X$. I need to show that $D=\{\sigma \in S_A: |M(\sigma)|<\infty\}$ is normal in $S_A$.

I know that I need to show that $D$ is the kernel of some action, but I do not know how define that action. (Sorry for the bad notation.)

Comment: Reading my copy of Dummit and Foote, it looks like your question has a small but crucial error: you want to show that $D = \{\sigma \in S_{A} : |M(\sigma)| < \infty\}$ is normal in $S_{A}$ (not $M(X)$, as written above).

Comment: True, that should be a $\sigma$ instead of X.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma \in D$, and let $\tau \in S_{A}$. Our goal is to show that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \in D$, i.e. that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ stabilizes all but finitely many elements of $A$.

Indeed, let $\Omega = \tau(M(\sigma))$. Since $M(\sigma)$ is finite and $\tau$ is a bijection, $|\Omega| = |M(\sigma)| < \infty$. Further, if $a \in A \setminus \Omega$, then $\tau^{-1}(a) \notin M(\sigma)$, i.e. $\sigma(\tau^{-1}(a)) = \tau^{-1}(a)$, so

$$(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})(a) = \tau(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(a))) = \tau(\tau^{-1}(a)) = a$$

Hence, $M(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}) \subset \Omega$, whence $|M(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})| < \infty$, as desired.

Comment: I think you must mean $\Omega = \tau(M(\sigma))$.

Comment: @fredgoodman: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\def\inv{^{-1}}$
$\def\Fix{\operatorname{Fix}}$
This is just the same solution as given by Alex, but potentially with less extra notation.

Let's search for fixed points of $\tau \sigma \tau\inv$:
$$
\tau \sigma \tau\inv(a) = a \Leftrightarrow  \sigma (\tau\inv(a)) = \tau\inv(a).
$$
Show that this implies 
$$
F(\tau \sigma \tau\inv) = \tau(F(\sigma)), 
$$
and hence also

$$
M(\tau \sigma \tau\inv)  = \tau(M(\sigma)).
$$
Conclude $M(\tau \sigma \tau\inv)$ is finite iff $M(\sigma)$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

I woud prefer to make this a comment, but it's too long.

I was curious about the possibility suggested by the OP of defining an action with kernel $D$.  So first let $S_A$ act on the power set of $A$.  Then define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal P(A)$ by declaring two sets to be equivalent if their symmetric difference is finite.  The action of $S_A$ respects equivalence, so induces an action on $X_A = \mathcal P(A)/\sim$.  It's pretty clear that $D$ is contained in the kernel of this action.  We would still have to show that if $\tau \not\in D$ then $\tau$ acts non-trivially on $X_A$.  In fact, I claim that one can find an infinite set $B$ such that $B \cap \tau(B) = \emptyset$.  Unfortunately, this seems to require an actual argument, depending on the orbit structure of $\tau$, but it seems to work. (Split into cases that $\tau$ has an infinite orbit or not.)  Clearly this argument is not to be prefered, as it is more complicated, but nevertheless I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for sharing! An (I believe) equivalent formulation I explored was the following: let $\Gamma$ denote the space of functions $A \to \{0, 1\}$, modulo the equivalence relation $f \sim g$ if and only if $|f-g|$ has finite support. Then $S_{A}$ acts on $\Gamma$ by $\sigma \dot f = f \circ \sigma$, and the kernel is precisely $D$, though as you suggest, one inclusion is not so easy to show. I tried cooking up something similar by associating to $\sigma \in S_{A}$ the indicator function on $A$ supported at $a \in A$ if $\sigma(a) \neq a$, but I didn't get anywhere promising...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the same idea.  But at the end, you have to do something  little different.  You have taken (the indicator function of) the union of non-singleton orbits.  What you have to take instead is (the indicator function of) a set which intersects each non-singleton orbit, and whose complement also intersects each non-singleton orbit.  This is for the case that there exist infinitely many non-singleton orbits.  Otherwise, there exists an infinite orbit, $\{\sigma^k(a) : k \in \mathbb Z\}$.  In that case, take $\{\sigma^k(a) : k \in  2 \mathbb Z\}$.